# Changing the measure

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that I have the following situation: everything takes place on complex plane, I have some probabilistic measure $\mu$ and suppose that I have a family of function $(u_w)_w$ parametrised by $w$ where $w$ runs throught some subset of the complex plane (it may be whole $\mathbb{C}$). Suppose that all $u_w$'s are integrable with respect to the standard flat Lebesgue measure $dxdy$. Is it true that *almost* (with respect to $dxdy$) all $u_w$'s are $\mu$ integrable? How to prove this?

Comment: You can strip out some really unnecessary details by replacing your index set by $\mathbb{N}$ and changing the domain to $\mathbb{R}$. Then you have a sequence of functions which are integrable with respect to the Lebesgue measure and you are asking whether they are integrable with respect to some other measure. That would depend strongly on the functions (for instance are they bounded?) and $\mu$ (for instance is it absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure?)

Comment: Maybe I should have been more precise: the situation in which I'm interested in is the following: family $(u_w)_w$ consists from unbounded functions for example of the form $u_w(z)=\frac{1}{|z-w|}$ and the support of $\mu$ is some compact set $K \subset \mathbb{C}$ but it could be of measure  $dxdy$-zero.

Comment: Knowing that they are unbounded tells you that some of them might not be $\mu$-integrable. If $K$ actually has measure zero then you basically know nothing about that particular function from your original hypothesis. In short I still do not think you have said enough to unambiguously answer your question.